# How to add UINavigationBar prompt in RootViewController of UISplitviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

How i can dynamically show UINavigationBar promp in  RootViewController of UISplitviewcontroller

Like :
In my app delegate

```
// having UINavigationController inside
UISplitViewController *recentEntrySplitViewConntroller;

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recentEntrySplitViewConntroller,controller2, nil];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

[self.window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

so In viewDidLoad of RootViewController inside UINavigationController of recentEntrySplitViewConntroller, how can i show UINavigationBar promp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"My Prompt";
```